# PHP Sessions and Firefox / Chrome

Tags: php, session

I have a session stored in a specified folder. I am calling all the right starts but in firefox and in chrome the session id is right but no data is retrieved. works in IE

This is what the session data looks like:

> pid|s:3:"101";lcid|s:7:"1016553";gcid|s:7:"1019652";company|s:24:"RS
>   Graphics Sign Company";

I have tried specifying the save path and not specifying it.
I am running tests on a very simple script.

Has anyone ever run into an issue like this?

Comment: What about sharing the relevant code so we can help you? :)

Comment: Can you post your php code so we can see how you are starting the session?

Comment: The browser should be irrelevant, provided it's set up to accept your cookie, unless you're doing something funky and unusual in your session code.  If you could share said code that would be a big help as otherwise no answer anyone gives would be anything but a wild guess

Comment: where are you storing value? client or server?

Comment: I believe server... When i go to server files i can look at the session file as displayed above.. I did not want to post code because it is really long and I thought maybe someone would know some common issues that I could look for

Comment: @DanielHunter: can you at least add the relevant code. The code where you actually set and get the cookie

Comment: Gordon is correct, browser is irrelevant. You need to check if the session cookie is being accepted.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is that you take a look at the packets directly, to see what is happening to the cookies.

Install [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) on your client machine, and connect to a remote web server. (Wireshark will ignore localhost traffic.)